# How can revisionId in libraryDependencies be the latest available version in SBT 0.13+?

Tags: scala, sbt

How can I set the `revisionId` of the `libraryDependencies` setting to the latest available version in SBT `0.13+`. I was using `"*"` but didn't seem to work, e.g.:

```
"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "*"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SBT uses Ivy for dependency resolution, so it supports Ivy's dynamic revision syntax:

- `9.0.+` will match any version like `9.0.0` or `9.0.7`,
- `latest.release` will match the most recent release,
- `[9.0,)` matches all versions greater or equal to `9.0`, like for example `9.1.0`,
- `[9.0,9.1[` matches all versions greater or equal to `9.0` and strictly below `9.1`,
- and so on... : [Ivy dynamic revision syntax](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html#revision)

By default SBT will pick the latest available revision in a range, even in case of a dependency conflict, but this [can be customized](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#conflict-management).